# Order SQL query by 2 columns, and do mathematical operations first

Tags: sql, rating, reddit, frontpage

For a blog project, I want to order new posts by their rating and the datetime they were inserted.
But before ordering, I want to do some maths with those values to get get a good mix of popularity and currentness in the first posts showed. (like on reddits frontpage)

Can I do this with pure SQL? I dont think it is possible...
How would you approach this task?

Table: post
columns: pid title content author date time last_edited category password

Comment: Related [What formula should be used to determine “hot” questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)

Comment: Yes this can be done by pure SQL using a subquery to do the mathematical operations on it. Then order by the results of these calculations in the outer one. But show us the stucutres of these tables, what do you want to select from them, sample data/ desired output results and what have you tried so far.

Comment: all I tried so far was ordering by date/time and by rating seperate. I did not know how to do what i intended.

I actually thought about ordering the sql-data in php

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to create some expression and order by that - here I've tried to show how can it be:

```
declare @Temp_Data table (Rating int, [Date] datetime, [Text] nvarchar(max))

insert into @Temp_Data 
select 100, '20121001 15:00', 'Big rating post' union all
select 1, '20121013 15:00', 'Recent post' union all
select 20, '20121005 15:00', 'Other post'

select
    T.Rating, T.[Date], T.[Text]
from @Temp_Data as T
order by Rating * 200 - datediff(mi, [Date], getdate()) desc
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! but what exactly do you do in the select part of @Temp_Data?

Comment: well, I'm ordering rows by expression.
I need to order by Rating desc, but I also want recent posts to be near the top. So here I'm just sum Rating * 200 and -datediff in minutes and the sort by that value descending

the number 200 is just random number, you can make your own coefficient or may be you'll end up with another formula.